# Installing Rails 3.2/Ruby 1.9.2 on Ubuntu Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been working with Rails a while now, and want to setup a local VM'd server. For some reason, I keep running into errors while trying to install Rails on Ubuntu Server 11.10. Specifically, when running 'gem install rails', I get errors about not being able to build native extensions. Moreover, after I install Ruby, it says it's version 1.9.2, but after attempting to install Rails, it's telling me it's version 1.8.7... I'm at my wits end here, and Google isn't helping.

Can anyone give me a quick rundown of the commands to make this work, from Ruby installation onwards? It should be simple, but I'm obviously missing a step or two, and my Google Fu is failing me horribly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: install rails using **rvm** http://beginrescueend.com/

Comment: Here is a nice How-To: http://superuser.com/questions/291693/how-to-install-the-latest-version-of-ruby-and-ruby-on-rails-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I will *guess* that you're having trouble installing the `linecache19` gem.  You need to get a copy of the ruby source and install the gem with

```
gem install ruby-debug19 -- --with-ruby-include=/path/to/ruby/source
```

You know, someone should fix this...